# how to set default timeout for RobotFramework

Tags: appium, robotframework

## **1.issue**

I'm scripting for Android app with RobotFramework.
but the Click Element failed after Click Element, error message mentioned the element is not found.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login
        Click Element  id=sampleapp:id/loginSSOButton
        Click Element    id=sampleapp:id/user__userid
```

**ValueError: Element locator 'id=sampleapp:id/user__userid' did not match any elements.**

## **2.question**

How to set default timeout value for RobotFramework?
I referred Userguide and implement following, but immediately fail before 20 seconds passed.

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timeouts

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout    20 seconds

*** Test Cases ***
Login
        Click Element  id=sampleapp:id/loginSSOButton
        Click Element    id=sampleapp:id/user__userid
```

## **3.what I did**

For now I implement "Wait Until Page Contains Element",
but need to write at all steps where I set timeout.
it needs more costs for scripting and maintenance.
therefore I'm looking for more efficient way.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login
        Click Element  id=sampleapp:id/loginSSOButton
        Wait Until Page Contains Element  sampleapp:id/user__userid  20
        Click Element    id=sampleapp:id/user__userid
```

Comment: this is the test timeout. It will only timeout if the test will be running for more than 20 seconds. Since the element is no yet visible the test will fail immediately, so it is no use at all. It seems to that you will need to stick to your 3rd option.

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I found the way of using selenium library,
but it doesn't work for my android device...
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Set%20Selenium%20Implicit%20Wait

so if someone knows the better way, please comment